# PLSQL SUBSTR function ignore the trailing zero

Tags: plsql, substr

```
select TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR(10.31, INSTR (10.31, '.') + 1)) from dual
```

Above query returns `31` as the output. But below query returns `3` as the output.

```
select TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR(10.30, INSTR (10.30, '.') + 1)) from dual
```

How could I get the `30` as the output instead of the `3`?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson `"Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 18.4.0.0.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems (from comments) that you are starting with a numeric value that you want to turn into words, you should begin by splitting it into dollars and cents.

If you really need to use `substr` etc, then you could start with a known format, such as `to_char(amount,'fm9990.00')`, so it will be a string with exactly two decimal places. However, if you have the numeric value it would be easier to convert it into the desired units using arithmetic functions. Whole dollars are `trunc(amount)` and cents are `100 * mod(amount,1)`.

Another issue is that the `'Jsp'` date format approach can't handle zeroes. If you are using Oracle 12.2 or later there is a workaround using the `default on conversion error` clause:

```
create table demo
( amount number(6,2) );

insert into demo values (10.3);
insert into demo values (.25);
insert into demo values (25);

select amount
     , nvl(to_char(to_date(trunc(amount) default null on conversion error,'J'),'Jsp'),'Zero') as dollars
     , nvl(to_char(to_date(100 * mod(amount,1) default null on conversion error,'J'),'Jsp'),'Zero') as cents
from   demo;

  AMOUNT DOLLARS      CENTS
-------- ------------ -------------
   10.30 Ten          Thirty
   25.00 Twenty-Five  Zero
    0.25 Zero         Twenty-Five
```

In 12.1 you could get around it using an inline function (maybe not a bad idea even in later versions, to simplify the rest of the query):

```
with
     function to_words(num number) return varchar2 as
     begin
         return
             case num
                 when 0 then 'Zero'
                 else to_char(to_date(num,'J'),'Jsp')
             end;
     end; 
select amount
     , to_words(trunc(amount)) as dollars
     , to_words(100 * mod(amount,1)) as cents
from   demo;
```

For values greater than 5373484 (the Julian representation of date '9999-12-31'), you can use this from [Ask Tom: Spell the number](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650) (converted here to a WITH clause, but you can create it as a standalone function):

```
with function spell_number
    ( p_number in number )
    return varchar2
as
    -- Tom Kyte, 2001:
    -- https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650
    l_num    varchar2(50) := trunc(p_number);
    l_return varchar2(4000);

    type myarray is table of varchar2(15);

    l_str myarray :=
        myarray
        ( ''
        , ' thousand '
        , ' million '
        , ' billion '
        , ' trillion '
        , ' quadrillion '
        , ' quintillion '
        , ' sextillion '
        , ' septillion '
        , ' octillion '
        , ' nonillion '
        , ' decillion '
        , ' undecillion '
        , ' duodecillion ');
begin
    for i in 1 .. l_str.count loop
        exit when l_num is null;
    
        if substr(l_num, length(l_num) -2, 3) <> 0 then
            l_return := to_char(to_date(substr(l_num, length(l_num) - 2, 3), 'J'), 'Jsp') || l_str(i) || l_return;
        end if;
        l_num := substr(l_num, 1, length(l_num) - 3);
    end loop;

    return l_return;
end spell_number;
select amount
     , spell_number(trunc(amount)) as dollars
     , spell_number(100 * mod(amount,1)) as cents
from   demo
/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like first workaround is answering for my issue. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Any solution for numbers greater than 5373484? Because `julian date must be between 1 and 5373484`. Query fail when number is greater than 5373484.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually surprised that your current query is even running without error, given that Oracle's `SUBSTR` function is supposed to operate on *strings*, not numbers.  That being said, if you properly use your current query with strings, then it works:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('10.30', INSTR ('10.30', '.') + 1)) FROM dual;  -- returns 30
```

A more compact (though not necessarily more performant) way of doing this might be to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('10.30', '[0-9]+$') FROM dual;
```

This would retain only digits appearing after the decimal point, in the case that a decimal point be present.  Otherwise, it would just return all numbers for inputs which have no decimal component.

Comment: "_I am actually surprised that your current query is even running without error_" Same here. Mistakenly forgot to surrounded the number with quotes and Oracle did the type conversion for me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Bishan By the way, if you _are_ really working with numbers, then something like this might be what you want here: `SELECT 10.31 - FLOOR(10.31) AS output FROM dual` ... that is, if you just want to capture the decimal component of a number.

Comment: Actually I am trying to display the number value in words. (like ten and thirty cents, ten and five cents etc..). Currently I am using this command with decimal part of the given number `(TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR(inputNum, INSTR (inputNum, '.') + 1)),'J'),'JSP'))` and this gives me `THREE` for both `10.03` and `10.30`

Comment: We can fix the formatting issue, but is it OK not to have zero values? What is your Oracle version?